# Maximise Wireless AC output?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My current networking setup:

- HyperOptic 1Gbps Broadband
- Brand new wireless AC router TP-link archer c58
- Cat 6 Ethernet between router and "modem"
- iPhone 7 plus for testing of Wi-Fi
- Open plan room with no intermediary walls, with phone about 70cm away from router

---

- Router settings:
- 80Mhz channel width
- Channel: auto
- Mode: n/ac mixed
- Frequency: 5Ghz
- Transmit power: high

Now, i fully accept that i can never expect the full **1gbps** over WiFi, but i am hoping to achieve greater than the current max speed i am reaching now, which is **90mbps** given that it's wireless ac over cat 6, etc etc. i was hoping for something in the low hundreds, is this expecting too much or am i doing something wrong? Would love some expert advice. Sorry if this is the wrong stack.

Comment: Have you tried configured the router to only use 802.11ac?  Do you have any other devices connected wirelessly that does not support 802.11ac?

Comment: If the specification here http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C58.html#specifications is right, the WAN port is only 100Mbps. Which would explain the speed you are getting.

Comment: @Ramhound Yep, tried that also, i believe some devices don't have AC however so needed to revert soon after.

Comment: @DavidMarshall unbelievable! Why even bother supporting AC then.. new router then?

Comment: Well you can use it between devices on the LAN but it looks like you need to look for a router with a gigabit WAN port.

Comment: @xBroak - non-802.11ac devices will cause 802.11ac devices to run at slower speeds.